# clang: error: linker command failed on vscode

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

I got the following error. How can I fix it? It's my first time to compile multiple sources on vscode.

**Error message**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Vector::size()", referenced from:
      sqrt_sum(Vector&) in user-9f738c.o
  "Vector::operator[](int)", referenced from:
      sqrt_sum(Vector&) in user-9f738c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**user.cpp**

```
#include "Vector.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double sqrt_sum(Vector& v)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i)
        sum += sqrt(v[i]);
    return sum;
}

int main() {

}
```

**Vector.h**

```
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(int s);
        double& operator[](int i);
        int size();
    private:
        double* elem;
        int sz;
};
```

**Vector.cpp**

```
#include "Vector.h"

Vector::Vector(int s):elem {new double[s]}, sz{s} 
{
}

double& Vector::operator[](int i)
{
    return elem[i];
}

int Vector::size()
{
    return sz;
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-std=c++11", "-O2", "-g", "user.cpp"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

---

Update 1

Finished compiling after adding Vector.cpp

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-std=c++11", "-O2", "-g", "user.cpp", "Vector.cpp"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

---

Update 2

Seems it worked. Thank you all!

**user.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include "Vector.h"

using namespace std;

double sqrt_sum(Vector& v)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i)
        sum += sqrt(v[i]);
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    Vector v(4);
    int sum = sqrt_sum(v);
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

**Result**

```
$ ./a.out
-2147483648
```

Comment: Your **Error message** says clang, but your **tasks.json** says g++.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure the difference. I'll check it.

Comment: Where is `Vector.cpp` in the compile command?

Comment: I will try to add Vector.cpp into tasks.json

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you.